# How force windows XP to only send traffic via chosen VPN

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vpn

We are using VPN's in our network and we encounter the following problem:
When VPN crashes during connection with remote host some applications automatically send subsequent requests to the host directly (using internet connection given computer have)
We would like to avoid this situation. ie: if VPN crashes windows should prevent all the applications from sending any traffic what so over and wait for the VPN to reconnect.

We can't just switch off internet connection for given computer because it's needed to connect to the VPN in the first place.

Help please :)

Comment: I've also had this problem, I'm hoping someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm really bad at Windows-related questions and haven't used it for ages, but for me this seems like a routing problem.

Try setting up the routing table on the PCs without a default route, just add a route to the VPN gateway via your default router on your local network.  That way only the VPN gateway can be reached outside your local network.  Once the VPN is up, it should configure its default route via the VPN interface.

Comment: Unfortunaely we have many computers and many vpn's so this won't work; we need to do that on every computer individually

Comment: And can't you distribute system scripts somehow to the PCs?  You could also set up firewall rules in a script to prevent connections to anything but the VPN gateway.  It's not clear either whether connections to other local computers are allowed: if yes, and only connections made to nodes outside your network should be disallowed, then you can also set up filtering on your router/firewall.